# Network Protocol and Listening Port Number with Unity3D and Matlab

Tags: matlab, unity-game-engine, udp, tcp, motion-detection

I can stream motion capture data *live* from [Xsens MVN Studio](https://www.xsens.com/mvn-studio-pro/) into Unity3D and animate a character with it in *real-time*, because the Unity3D character *listens* to port number 9763 of the same machine and receives the motion data from there, which means Xsens MVN Studio sends the motion data to that port. In the attachment, please see the attached image `localhost:9763`

Where does this port number come from? I mean who decides the port number? I could configure this live streaming between Unity3D and Xsens MVN Studio, because Xsens people provide a manual for the Unity3D plug-in, so that is how I knew about it...

My other question is that: Now, I would like to do the exact same thing with Matlab; i.e. get Unity3D to stream data live into Matlab and get back whatever Matlab produces, etc... I have found a simple Matlab script online that apparently does this with a remote *website*:

```
t = tcpip('www.EXAMPLE_WEBSITE.com', 80);
set(t, 'InputBufferSize', 30000); 
fopen(t);
fprintf(t, 'GET /'); 
pause(1) 
while (get(t, 'BytesAvailable') > 0) 
t.BytesAvailable
DataReceived = fscanf(t) 
end
fclose(t); 
delete(t);
clear t
```

The code comment says: I should substitute `www.EXAMPLE_WEBSITE.com` with an actual website or any remote application with which I wish to communicate. But firstly, what is the www replacement for the Matlab application on the same machine (`localhost`??) and secondly, how do I find out which port number Matlab can send data to and Unity can listen to?

I would appreciate it if someone please help me understand these concepts...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. I think they decide port number. You can choose port (Ps: Only one app can use same port at the same time.)
2. I think Matlab needs to behave like server. So unity request calculation result from Matlab. Matlab listens requests and gives response. I don't know how you can do in Matlab but you can request calculation result from Unity3D to Matlab server with using [WWW](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html) class.

Comment: Thank you Barış. This is helpful.